# mysqli_real_escape_string is not escaping the strings

Tags: php, mysql

I know it's probably obviously in front of my face, because according to every example I looked at they look identical to me. The form will submit without escaping anything, and store it in MySQL.

I've tried changing the order, and

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require_once("config.php");

  $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB);
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

  // Validate & Insert Grievance
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Define and set variables as Empty
    $name = $email = $location = $title = $grievance = "";

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);
    $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["location"]);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["title"]);
    $grievance = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["grievance"]);

    if ($name != "" && $email != "" && $location != "" && $title != "" && $grievance != "") {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO grievances (name, email, location, title, grievance, ip_address, deleted) VALUES('$name','$email','$location','$title','$grievance','$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]', false)";

    ?><script>document.getElementById("grievance-sucess").style.display = "block";</script><?php

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }


    } else {
    // Something isn't filled out
    ?><script>document.getElementById("grievance-error").style.display = "block";</script><?php
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: can you share sample io

Comment: For one, `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection.

Comment: If the data is stored in the database, doesn't this mean it works?

Comment: It is stored in the database, but I'm trying to escape the string and prevent any injection. For example, I can still put an alert script in one of the input fields and when the page loads it still calls that script. Is my understanding wrong? I thought this was suppose to escape brackets for example.

Comment: The database escaping (mysqli_real_escape_string) is to escape problematic SQL characters.  There is no one size fits all 'escape'.  Escape appropriately for each task in hand.

Comment: _“For example, I can still put an alert script in one of the input fields and when the page loads it still calls that script. Is my understanding wrong?”_ - yes, absolutely and massively. These are two completely different _contexts_. You take measures against SQL injection, to make sure that all the data lands in the database correctly, and does not cause errors or even make an attack on the database possible, while you are performing the insert. Whether something other than the database might execute JavaScript or not, is absolutely irrelevant at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to use RegEx to strip everything except for spaces, letters, numbers, periods, commas, and so forth. It's seems like it's a lot more complicated then it needs to be, but going to go this route since mysqli_real_escape_string is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is preventing SQL injection, I'd recommend using prepared statements:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Additionally, to answer your original question, it depends on the data you are passing in.  mysqli_real_escape_string will only change strings if they contains characters that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent injection of JavaScript code you should use [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when echoing the data from the database

Comment: That still allows scripts to get through such as <script>alert('Can I get through?');</script>